# Can you help identify this olive green space fighter lego set?

Tags: set-identification, technic

This set was bought about 10 years ago for my son. It is predominantly olive green with red trimmings. It has stickers with WARRING A-347 written on them. It has some moving parts that seem like Technic LEGO. It appears to be a fighter jet with large legs (like a star wars vessel). It may be more than one vehicle and no doubt some of its parts are in our LEGO brick bin. I'm selling my son's extensive collection and engaged in the arduous task of completing each set. Any clues are much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Based on

- [6016457: Right Shell 3X12 W/Bow/Angle](https://brickset.com/parts/6016457/right-shell-3x12-w-bow-angle)
- [6016465: Circle 90G 6X6 Roof Tile](https://brickset.com/parts/6016465/circle-90g-6x6-roof-tile)

Both in Olive Green

This is from [70164-1: Hurricane Heist](https://brickset.com/sets/70164-1/Hurricane-Heist)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly!